# Passenger Error message: Could not find cancan-1.6.5 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, deployment, passenger

I'm trying to deploy a Rails app to a Ubuntu 10.04 Lucid. I keep on getting this error:
`Error message: Could not find cancan-1.6.5 in any of the sources (Bundler::GemNotFound)`

Even though the gem is there. I packaged the gems and did a bundle local. Didn't work.

So then I tried bundle install and didn't worked either.

I did use RVM, but I'm using the same thing in my development machine and runs with no problem.

I get this too on the error page: `Further information about the error may have been written to the application's log file. Please check it in order to analyse the problem.` So I go to look for the production.log file and it's not even there, there is just a development.log file

Comment: I'm using Ruby 1.9 and Rails 3. When I run `bundle show builder` i get this /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352-libopenssl/gems/builder-3.0.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have an environment specific gem requirement.

Make sure you don't have any `config.gem` references in your config/environments/*.rb files.

Comment: I have this in boot.rb
require 'rubygems'
# Set up gems listed in the Gemfile.
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path('../../Gemfile', __FILE__)
require 'bundler/setup' if File.exists?(ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'])

Comment: And this in application.rb if defined?(Bundler)
  Bundler.require *Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end

Comment: Should I add this to my application.rb file? Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)

Comment: rails is doing that automatically anyways. where in the code is the reference to 'cancan'?

Comment: Somehow it was fixed and I'm not exactly sure how. I was running commands on the shell, checking versions, and then it just worked. I think what happens is that I have gems in two different locations and my app was looking at one location while bundle was looking somewhere else, not sure. For future reference, run this command, it might help: `gem environment`